# Why is the existence of one-way functions not proven?

Tags: one-way-functions

Weisstein, Eric W. "[One-Way Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/One-WayFunction.html)." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource.:

> The existence of one-way functions is not proven.

Why not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function

Comment: Some mathematical facts are hard to prove, simply. I don't think we really know why.

Comment: You want a proof that something isn’t done because we are not clever enough, but because it is impossible. Such proofs are usually very simple or completely out of our reach.